# coldfusion and sql server connection string

Tags: coldfusion, odbc, database-connection

I am using coldfusion.

I have dedicated database server and shared webserver. Both are located on different server.

I do not have access of coldfusion administrator where I can create datasource.

I need help to create database connection in the code and needs to createDatasource Name.

Comment: if you have the CFAdmin password you can create a datasource using their api http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=basiconfig_37.html If you don't have the password you're SOL.

Comment: Your shared hosting company of your web server should be able to create the datasource for you, or provide you a control panel to do it yourself.  For example, PLESK control panel has the ability to allow you to create a datasource.

Comment: I am using shared server, I do not have access of CFAdmin. They have provided me their own database server but I want to use my own dedicated server which is hosted by different company. They told me either I have to import db or I have to create db connection string.

Comment: I can create datasource through control panel, but I can not modify database server name. They have provided their own database server.

Comment: If they are not willing to allow you to link to your own database, you may want to consider finding another hosting provider.

Comment: You may want to find a new hosting company. Try someplace like hostcfml.com I know for a fact they have a fantastic ControlPanel

Comment: If they told you to import the db **OR** create a db connection string then it seems possible. They should be able to provide you the steps necessary to do so.

Comment: How we define ColdFusion connections in code, like in other languages. I know We can do that at the server level, using the ColdFusion Administrator, which is a web-based interface. Any Idea?

Answer (score -1):

I know this does not exactly answer your question, but may help a bit. Here I goes:
You can  create a DSN less connection like example below. You can store the connection in Application.cfm/cfc:

```
<cfscript>
classLoader = createObject("java", "java.lang.Class");
classLoader.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
dm = createObject("java","java.sql.DriverManager");

con = dm.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=server; PORT=3306; DATABASE=database; USER=username; PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3;");

st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.ExecuteQuery("Select xyz FROM table");
q = createObject("java", "coldfusion.sql.QueryTable").init(rs);
//the query is stored in the variable q

</cfscript>
```

ps: reference http://www.hostmysite.com/support/mysql/coldfusionstring/

Comment: Do not roll your own database connections. It is far less efficient than using a DSN. Not to mention easier to get wrong if you do not know what you are doing. [1: Huge number of connections to the database server](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:51016) --> [2: Resolution - Huge number of connections ...](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:51085). Also, that is not a good example to follow. The code does not release any of the resources and uses a Type 1 driver to boot (poorest).